# console not finding the right path

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

If understood correctly inside an array you must use [] to access it, why not able to access this id ?  doing something wrong ?

```
  console.log(orders?[0].id);
```

getting : Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number[]'.ts(2339).
I'am able to access this one console.log(orders); and what i'am seeing there is this :
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The question mark behind the orders array is definitely wrong, I assume you wanted to check for orders not being falsey first before trying to access index 0. If that's the case then you need additional dot behind the question mark or it will be interpreted like a ternary expression by the compiler.
If you wanted to just check that element at index 0 exists then you should move the question mark behind the square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with brackets, you still need to use the dot:

```
orders?.[0].id
```

Comment: If you’re getting an error without the optional chaining then you’re likely trying to get the value before orders is defined.

Comment: then what to do to get same result without  optional chaining ?

Comment: You can make sure that orders is defined before trying to get the id. if (orders) { id = orders[0].id } OR orders && orders[0].id

Comment: at the moment it is searching from [0]  (orders?.[0].id), how to have it search from everything ?

Comment: Can you clarify? Might be better to create a new question

Comment: inside that order is 13 array and at the moment we are selecting from [0] how to select from all ?

Comment: What does that mean though? You want an array of 13 id’s? Map over the array and convert to id’s.